# Is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ the same as $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Consider the function $d : \mathbb{R} × \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(x_1, x_2) = |x_1 − x_2|^2$.
Does $d$ define a metric on $\mathbb{R}$? If so, prove it. If not, justify why not.

What I am confused with here is whether $x_1, x_2$ are $x_1=(a,b)$ or if $x_1=a$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$? If $x_1=(a,b),x_2=(c,d)$ then $|x_1 − x_2|^2= (a-c)^2+(b-d)^2$, right?

Comment: No, both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are numbers and not vectors so $d(a,b)=\lvert a-b\rvert^2=(a-b)^2$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R$

Comment: For your title question, I would regard $\mathbb{R}^2$ as shorthand for $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, so they are the same. So you could write $d:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, but that would still leave $x_1$ and $x_2$ as elements of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. each being one-dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $d$ is $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ which is the set of ordered pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1$ is a real number and $x_2$ is also a real number.

Parentheses are used in ambiguous ways in mathematics, and you have to know the context to know which way is intended. The notation $d(x_1,x_2)$ means that $d$ is a function with two arguments (two input parameters) named $x_1,x_2$. This has *nothing* to do with open interval notation such as $(a,b)$ which means a subset of $\mathbb R$ defined as 
$$(a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid a < x < b\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The metric is defined on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\cong\Bbb R^2$.

The first two properties are easy.  For the triangle inequality, do we have $(x-z)^2+(z-y)^2\ge(x-y)^2$?

No.  Try $x=1,z=2,y=3$.

Comment: Your counter example isn't a counter example at all: if x = 1, y = 3, and z = 2, we have d(x,z) = d(y,z) = 1, and d(x,y) = 2, and as 1 + 1 = 2, the triangle inequality is satisfied.

Comment: The difference is _squared_.  @Harry Wilson

Comment: Ah, so it is! You have my apologies: I assumed d was d^2.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ is the set of ordered pairs of elements of $\Bbb R$. Therefore a function $f:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a real-valued function of two real variables. Namely, $f(x_1,x_2)$ is shorthand for $f((x_1,x_2))$.